# Height of div not increasing according to the content

Tags: css, height

The height of my div is not increasing with the content.

HTML :

```
<div style="position: relative;min-height: 200px;clear: both;margin: 25px 0;border:1px;solid black;width:500px;">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <label class="tab"> Review</label>

            <div class="tabcontent">
                 /* contents here */
                <div id="moviereviews">
                </div>
               </div>

        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <label class="tab">Comments</label>

        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab
{
    background: #eee; 
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin-left: -1px; 
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;

}

.tabcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

I tried adding `overflow: hidden;` to the main div. But yet it is not increasing the height. Also I have a footer div after the above shown code as:

```
<div class="footer"></div>

// CSS
.footer {
margin-top: 10px;
background: #ECE5B6;
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
height: 100px;
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you've `position: absolute;` for `tabcontent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all. I think may be some other css is making my code from not working according to yours. I solved it by adding `overflow:hidden;` to both

```
<div style="position: relative;min-height: 200px;overflow: hidden;clear: both;margin: 25px 0;border:1px solid black;width:500px;">
```

and `.tabcontent` div.

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbXZf/1/)**</kbd>

Remove **`right: 0; bottom: 0;`** property and add **`width:100%; height:auto;`**. you can set  width on yourself either fixed or relative.

```
.tabcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

Comment: nop..for me itz not showing the rest content in the div..itz showing only upto the height of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
.tabcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  height:100%;
}
```

Here's your demo http://jsfiddle.net/m5Q7Q/

Comment: nop..for me itz not showing the rest content in the div..itz showing only upto the height of the div.

Comment: lol. than maybe you have more code to share with us. How in fiddle is works perfect and at you isn't working ok?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `height:auto` and remove `bottom:0` in class `tabcontent`

```
.tabcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  height:auto; /*Added Line*/
}
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/canajiro/1/edit)**.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `bottom: 0;` from `.tabcontent`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `height:auto` in tab content and also make sure `width is 100%`

And take a look at fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bedPj/1/).

Have made changes and hope it works.

```
.tab
{
    background: #eee; 
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin-left: -1px; 
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;


}

.tabcontent {
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
      background: white;
     height:auto;
    width:100%;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you too

```
.tab
{
    background: #eee; 
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin-left: -1px; 
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;    
}

.tabcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/rRgG9/)